# Python Pillow Image to PDF and then merging memory issues

Tags: python, pdf-generation, python-imaging-library

Goal:
Convert finite number of files in .jpg format and merge them into one PDF file.

Expected result:
Files from folder are successfully converted and merged into one pdf file at specified location.

Problem:
When size of files exceed certain number, in my tests it was around 400 mb the program crashes with following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kaczk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 498, in _save
    fh = fp.fileno()
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MakePDF.py", line 10, in <module>
    im1.save(pdf1_filename, "PDF" ,resolution=1000.0, save_all=True, append_images=imageList)
  File "C:\Users\kaczk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2084, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Users\kaczk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py", line 46, in _save_all
    _save(im, fp, filename, save_all=True)
  File "C:\Users\kaczk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py", line 175, in _save
    Image.SAVE["JPEG"](im, op, filename)
  File "C:\Users\kaczk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py", line 770, in _save
    ImageFile._save(im, fp, [("jpeg", (0, 0) + im.size, 0, rawmode)], bufsize)
  File "C:\Users\kaczk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 513, in _save
    fp.write(d)
MemoryError
```

After running the program with task manager i noticed that indeed the computer runs out of ram memory when executing this program. Below is the code used.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
fileList = os.listdir(r'C:\location\of\photos\folder')
imageList = []
im1 = Image.open(os.path.join(r'C:\location\of\photos\folder',fileList[0]))
for file in fileList[1:]:
   imageList.append(Image.open(os.path.join(r'C:\location\of\photos\folder',file)))
pdf1_filename =  r'C:\location\of\pdf\destination.pdf'
im1.save(pdf1_filename, "PDF" ,resolution=500.0, save_all=True, append_images=imageList)
```

Is there an easy mistake I am making here regarding memory usage? Is there different module that would make the task easier while working with more and larger files? I will be very grateful for all help.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old but since I got there struggling with the same issue, here is an answer.

You simply have to close your images after using them:

```
im1.close()
for i in imageList:
    i.close()
```

This solved it for me.

PS: take a look at `glob`, it eases working with paths a lot.